# Sencha SDK Tools does not Minified app-all.js

Tags: extjs4, extjs, minify

I'm using Sencha SDK Tools **2 Beta 3** and ExtJS 4.0.7 in Windows 7 64bit.
After I build my project, the **app-all.js** file is **not minified**.

This is the **.JSB3** file (that was generated by Sencha):

```
{
    "projectName": "Project Name",
    "licenseText": "Copyright(c) 2012 Company Name",
    "builds": [
        {
            "name": "All Classes",
            "target": "all-classes.js",
            "options": {
                "debug": true
            },
            "files": [
                // All Classes
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Application - Production",
            "target": "app-all.js",
            "compress": true,
            "files": [
                {
                    "path": "",
                    "name": "all-classes.js"
                },
                {
                    "path": "",
                    "name": "app.js"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "resources": []
}
```

And Sencha **result** in command prompt: (Without Errors)

```
Loaded 2 Builds

Creating the "All Classes" target as "all-classes.js"
  - 256 file(s) included in this target.
    + // All Classes
* Parse all-classes.js with options:
- debug: true
- debugLevel: 1

Creating the "Application - Production" target as "app-all.js"
- 2 file(s) included in this target.
    + all-classes.js
+ app.js
* Parse app-all.js with options:
- debug: false
- debugLevel: 1
* Compress and obfuscate app-all.js...
Copy resources...
Done building!
```

FUI: My file has Unicode characters.

Thank you in Advance.

**Update:** (Folder Structure, Simplified)

```
MyApp
  - app
  -- controller
  --- mycontroller.js
  -- model
  --- mymodel.js
  -- store
  --- mystore.js
  -- view
  --- myview.js
  - ext
  - app.js
  - index.html
```

*(Folders don't have file extensions)*

Comment: Did you get the controller classes inside ` "files"` or is it only `models and controllers` ?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't understand what you ask.

Comment: Did the `app.jsb3` file contain the definitions for the `controller` classes of your application ? In mine, the `app.jsb3` file only contains definitions for `models and store` and it doesn't have controllers defined in it.

Comment: My **app.jsb** contains **controller** class: "clsName": "Ext.app.Controller"

Comment: Oh, ok thank you. Mine doesn't :S

Comment: Will it be possible for you to paste your project folder structure to this post ?

Comment: Yes, of course. I've updated my post due to your request.

Comment: Even mine has the same project structure as yours, but controllers are not added. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was about an internal error.
I've replaced **float** with **'float'** in my JS File and now it works.